# RecyclerView + Images lags on some devices

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, universal-image-loader, android-glide

I have very strange bug, and only on HTC One:
RecyclerView with images freezes.

I tried UniversalImageLoader,

```
mDisplayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true) 
            .cacheInMemory(true) 
            .cacheOnDisc(true) 
            .delayBeforeLoading(100)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
            .build();
```

and loading,

```
ImageViewAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(mainIcon);
ImageLoader.getInstance().cancelDisplayTask(imageAware);
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageAware, mDisplayOptions);
```

Pause when list scrolled

```
if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
    ImageLoader.getInstance().resume();
} else {
    ImageLoader.getInstance().pause();
}
```

Also, i tried Picasso, Glide and AQuery.

```
Glide.clear(mainIcon);
glide.load(url)
     .centerCrop()
     .override(targetSize, targetSize) // target size - 200
     .dontAnimate()
     .skipMemoryCache(true)
     .priority(Priority.LOW)
     .into(mainIcon);
```

But lags still on HTC devices (Samsung S4, LG L70, and Samsung galaxy ace 1 (!) work without feezes).

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure you have `StrictMode` enabled to point out network and disk I/O on the main application thread. If `StrictMode` is not complaining, use method tracing to try to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't any network connections in main thread. I think, glide/picasso/UIL use background thread for downloading and decoding bitmaps.

Comment: Used properly, they do. However, you say that "RecyclerView with images freezes". In Android, when it comes to the UI, "freezes" usually means that something is tying up the main application thread. The most likely culprit there is disk I/O and network I/O. So, configure `StrictMode`. Perhaps there is some edge case with your particular HTC device that is causing some work that normally happens on a background thread to be done on the main application thread.